# Mysql subtraction with 2 table

Tags: mysql, subtraction

Need your help on MySQL. How do i write the query below.

Objective: To summarize each stock items with total incoming, total outgoing & balance.

I've try and cannot work

```
SELECT
part_db.part_num,
part_db.variant,
SUM(uts_details.qty) AS UTS,
SUM(sir_details.qty) AS SIR,
(UTS - SIR) AS bal
FROM part_db
LEFT OUTER JOIN uts_details ON part_db.part_num = uts_details.part_num
LEFT OUTER JOIN sir_details ON part_db.part_num = sir_details.part_num
GROUP BY part_db.part_num
```

Output: Unknown column 'UTS' in field list

I've 3 table here,

#### Part_db (Parts Database)

- Part_num (Primary Key)
- Variant

#### Uts_details (Incoming)

- Uts_no (Primary Key)
- Part_num
- Qty

#### Sir_details (Outgoing)

- Sir_no (Primary Key)
- Part_num
- Qty

Output :-

`part_num: 12345
variant: ABC
total_uts: 400
total_sir: 300
(total_uts - total_sir): 100`

The output should show all the parts with and without transaction.

Appreciates your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference a column alias in the same `select` statement.  Here's another option:

```
SELECT
    part_db.part_num,
    part_db.variant,
    SUM(uts_details.qty) AS UTS,
    SUM(sir_details.qty) AS SIR,
    SUM(uts_details.qty-sir_details.qty) AS bal
FROM part_db
    LEFT OUTER JOIN uts_details ON part_db.part_num = uts_details.part_num
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sir_details ON part_db.part_num = sir_details.part_num
GROUP BY part_db.part_num
```